# Convert microsoft equation 3.0 bytes to bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, razor, model-view-controller

I have stored microsoft equation 3.0 (as oledb object) as bytes in my database which came from ms access program.

I need to display this equation (as equation or as bitmap) in MVC website.
How can I do it?
I've been searching for 2 weeks now and no success.

Comment: First, I guess, you need to extract the bytes: [How to dump OLE field content into bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842719/access-vba-how-to-dump-ole-field-content-into-bytes).

Comment: @Gustav I already have the bytes.

Comment: Microsoft Equations are _very, very_ inflexible objects. There is [some evidence](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/microsoft-patches-equation-editor-flaw-without-fixing-the-source-code/) that Microsoft themselves can't modify the source code of the equation editor.  In the latest updates of Office, the equation editor has been removed altogether, so I can no longer test and develop code for it. I believe you could export these things to an image using automation, but it would be really inefficient anyway and unfit for use in a website.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thank you .. guess I'm going to have a huge problem then..